# PostreSQL - выборка постов по post_id

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица с данными

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно: сделать выборку данных тариким образом:

1. Выбрать все посты с уникальным post_id, отсортированные по status DESC, publish_date DESC
2. Отсортировать всё по status DESC, title ASC, publish_date DESC.
3. При этом, если если есть одинаковые status, то выбирается только последняя дата.

В данном примере должно вывести в следующем порядке
id = 4, id = 3

Comment: *Выбрать все посты с уникальным post_id* Это вообще как надо понимать эту фразу? Выбрать только записи, post_id из которых не встречается в других записях? Если да - то каким боком тут сортировка, а если нет - то что вообще имеется в виду?

Comment: В данном примере у записей 1,2,4,5 общий post_id. Как мне создать запрос, чтобы выбрать одну запись, у который

1 - максимальный status
2 - максимальный publish_date

Т.е. нужно показать записи с уникальным post_id, причем так, чтобы во время группировки учитывался status и publish_date

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT ON(post_id) * FROM  posts ORDER BY post_id, status DESC, publish_date DESC, title ASC
)
t 
ORDER BY status DESC, publish_date DESC, title ASC
```

Кажется вот, что я имел в виду)